# If x and y are integers, can I rewrite x < y + 1 as x ≤ y?

Tags: inequality

If x and y are integers, can I rewrite x < y + 1 as x ≤ y?

If x = 1 and y = 1,
x < y + 1 ≡ 1 < 1 + 1 ≡ 1 < 2, is true, and
x ≤ y ≡ 1 ≤ 1, is also true.

If x = 1 and y = 2,
x < y + 1 ≡ 1 < 2 + 1 ≡ 1 < 3, is true, and
x ≤ y ≡ 1 ≤ 2, is also true.

If x = 2 and y = 1,
x < y + 1 ≡ 2 < 1 + 1 ≡ 2 < 2, is false, and
x ≤ y ≡ 2 ≤ 1, is also false.

I don't see why x < y + 1 can't be rewritten as x ≤ y, or the other way around, when x and y are both integers.

Comment: If x and y are integers, Yes you can

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ and $y$ be integers.

If $x\le y$ then $x<y+1.$

On the other hand, if $x>y$ then $x \ge y+1$.

Thus, $x \le y $ if and only if $x<y+1$.

Answer (score 1):

For integers yes you can.

For any $x,y\in \mathbb R$ we have $y < y+1$ and there are three possibilities for $x$

i) $x \ge y+1$.  We were told this is not true.

ii) $y < x < y+ 1$.  If $y$ is an integer then there are no integers between $y$ and $y+1$.  So if $x$ and $y$ are integers then this is impossible.

iii) $x \le y$.

So we are told i) is false; and ii) is impossible.  That leaves only iii) $x \le y$.

Note: You can't do this in general if $x$ and/or $y$ aren't integers.

==== old obtuse answer below ====

Bear with me:

Let's suppose $A$ is a set of numbers.

If $k = \max A$, the maximum element (if any) in $A$.

Then if $x \in A$ we have to have $x \le k$.  That's obvious.  If $x$ is in $A$ and $k$ is the largest element in $A$ then $x$, an element, is at most, as large as the largest element.

If $A= $ the set of all integers less than $y+1$, an integer.  Then $y+1$ and anything larger is not in $A$ because $y+1 \not < y+1$ nor would anything larger be.  But $y < y+1$     so $y$ is in $A$. So $y = \max A$ because $y$ any thing larger is not.

Okay.  So $x < y+1$ means $x$ is in $A$ and so $x \le \max A = y$.

A bit overkill but....